# PageMethods, jQuery and JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, pagemethods

I am trying to call a `PageMethod` using jQuery like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public stataic string WebMethod(PostData data)
{
    //DO WORK
    return "a";
}
```

`PostData` class is as follows:

```
public class PostData
{
    public string Guid{get;set;}
    public string Action{get;set;}
    public string Id{get;set;}
}
```

I'm calling method from jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type="POST",
    url: 'url',
    data: JSON.stringify(b),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var t = $(c).html();
        $(c).html(t + "<br/>" + $.evalJSON(msg.d));
    },
    error: function (x, y) {
        var t = $(c).html();
        $(c).html(t + "<br/>" + $.evalJSON(x.responseText).Message);
    }
});
```

where `b` is like: `{"PostData":{"Guid":"b61dce32-690b-4409-b51a-a6012462e54e","Action":"Testing","Id":"3"}}`

I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'data'.
```

If I don't call `JSON.stringyfy` then I get this error:

```
Invalid JSON primitive: PostData.
```

I have tried this also `{"Guid":"b61dce32-690b-4409-b51a-a6012462e54e","Action":"Testing","Id":"3"}` but still get either

```
Invalid JSON primitive 'Guid'
```

or

```
Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'data'.
```

depending on if I call `JSON.stringify` or not.

I have also tried,

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string WebMethod(string data)
```

but got no where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first layered object names in the JSON should be the same names as your webservice arguments names.

```
{"data": {"Guid":"b61dce32-690b-4409-b51a-a6012462e54e","Action":"Testing","Id":"3"} }
```

Comment: yep, I knew I'm doing something silly but was not able to nail it. Thanks @jerone.

Comment: Thank You! I can't tell you how long I hunted around to see why I was getting a "500" error on my jquery.post. I never even thought of having to name my WebMethod argument inside the JSON I was sending from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
       var params = {"PostData":{"Guid":"b61dce32-690b-4409-b51a-a6012462e54e","Action":"Testing","Id":"3"}}; 
       var yourdata = jQuery.param(params);
```

pass

> yourdata

as your data instead of JSON.stringify(b).

Comment: nope @Furqan `jQuery.param` converts it into encoded string. I actually needed `data:` as the object name.