# Call ASP.NET WebMethod using AJAX JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, vb.net

I'm prototyping a new web app in ASP.NET with VB.NET codebehind that uses JQuery's AJAX to call a WebMethod, but I keep getting parsererrors. Here's my markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="testpage.aspx.vb" Inherits="WorkOrder_testpage" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnTest').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'testpage.aspx/testFunction',
                    //data: {a:'hello'},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#lblDebug').text(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
            $('#btnTest').focus();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
        <span id="lblDebug"></span><input type="button" id="btnTest" value="TEST" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my codebehind:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Partial Class WorkOrder_testpage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function testFunction() As String
        Dim jsonSer As New JavaScriptSerializer
        testFunction = jsonSer.Serialize("hello")
    End Function
End Class
```

**Things I have tried already:**

- omitting the dataType and/or contentType. This results in HTML being passed back upon success
- using "data.d" instead of "data" when outputting results on success. Only works when omitting dataType and/or contentType, no data shown.
- Adding an httpModules element to the web.config. No change, however there may be more I'm missing there.
- formatting my return data in just about every way imaginable. Always ends in a parsererrror. It always says, "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

**Where I THINK I'm going wrong:**

I think either I'm still not formatting my JSON right, in which case please illuminate me, or there is some configuration I am unaware of that is preventing my JSON from getting through.

I know this is similar to about 80 other questions, but none I have found so far have seemed to be of any help.

My sources of help:
[asp.net jquery ajax json: Simple example of exchanging data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269622/asp-net-jquery-ajax-json-simple-example-of-exchanging-data)
[PageMethods, jQuery and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954628/pagemethods-jquery-and-json)
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/12/jquery-ajax-json-example-in-aspnet.html
And many many more.

**Update 6/10/14**

I tried Mun's answer below with similar/same results. If anybody has done this with the same structure, I would like to know how much, if any, you had to add or configure in your web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to call your webmethod via *PageMethods* instead of jQuery.

Code Behind (in C# but easily convertible to VB.NET):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SayHello(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

WebForm:

```
$("#btnTest").click(function() {
    PageMethods.SayHello("Test", function(result) {
      alert(result);  // Should show "Hello Test"
    });
});
```

The Javascript proxy for your *SayHello* method will automatically be created by the Script Manager, allowing it to be called client-side.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting HTML back. I used the same format. Is there something else I'm missing?